# VSCode 'cannot open source file "boost/serialization/serialization.hpp" (dependency of "mlpack/core.hpp")' when trying to include mlpack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mlpack

I am trying to use mlpack in VSCode. I have installed the library using brew, and have included the path in c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_2/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, when I try and include core.hpp, I get the following error:

```
cannot open source file "boost/serialization/serialization.hpp" (dependency of "mlpack/core.hpp")C/C++(1696)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? It's my understanding that brew handles the dependencies, is this wrong?

Here is my current tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build all files",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp",
                "--include-directory=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_2/include",
                "--include-directory=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.75.0_3/include",
                "--include-directory=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/include",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/app",
                "-larmadillo",
                "-lmlpack"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: if I add paths for boost and armadillo:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_2/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.75.0_3/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/include"
            ],
```

the error becomes:

```
'mlpack/core.hpp' file not found
```

Comment: Show your `tasks.json`

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: You need to setup the include directories in both tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json. c_cpp_properties.json is for Intellisense and tasks.json is for building.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I tried adding them as command line arguments but I still get the same error

Comment: Does `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_2/include/mlpack/core.hpp` exist?

Comment: Yeah it does. If I add the same paths as command line arguments using --include-directory then the file is found, however I then get errors for -larmadillo and -lmlpack stating library not found. If i don't include these arguments I get a list of errors stating undefined symbols for arm64

Comment: Add the arguments then solve the linker problems. ***library not found*** means you need to add the correct linker paths to your `tasks.json` using -L

Comment: I tried adding the line `"-L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/include/armadillo"` but this doesn't seem to have resolved the issue

Comment: ***/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/include/armadillo*** does not seem like a correct folder for a `.so`  or a `.a` file.

Comment: `armadillo` appears to be a header file. There is a lib folder, however if i try and use `"-L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/lib/libarmadillo.10.4.1.dylib"` then i recieve an error stating that a directory could not be found

Comment: The argument for `-L` is supposed to be a folder. Try `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/lib` instead of `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/10.4.1_1/lib/libarmadillo.10.4.1.dylib`

Comment: Using `"--library-directory=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_2/lib"` and the equivalent for mlpack I was able to get it working, thanks for all your help! I'll add an answer later on describing how to fix it in case anyone else has the same issue in the future

Comment: `-L`  is the same as `--library-directory=`. `-I` is the same as `--include-directory=`

Comment: Ah okay, I'll change those over. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In includePath just add this:

`"/opt/homebrew/opt/boost/include"`